# Cannot assign values from functions to dictionary array Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've encountered the following error in two different scenarios that may be related. The error is:

> lldb Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is the code for the first scenario:

```
db.collection("properties").getDocuments()
{
    (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err
    {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
    }
    else
    {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            var propertyData = [String:[String]]()
            let listingType = (document.get("listingType") as! [String])
            propertyData["listingType"]![0] = listingType[0]

        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to get a list of properties that I have already set in Firestore. I can print the listingType variable to the console and it successfully prints "Sale". However when I assign the variable it then gives that error.

I have experienced the same issue when using the location manager functions. If I get the user's current location coordinates, when I try to add those coordinates to a global dictionary it throws the same error. I am writing the code in Swift 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just assign something to `[0]` since the array is initially nil

```
if propertyData["listingType"] == nil {
    propertyData["listingType"] = [listingType[0]] //Create a new array with the string
} else {
    propertyData["listingType"]![0] = listingType[0]
}
```

Comment: Joakim, thank you very much!! I see the issue now, I set the dictionary as empty initially!!